# Getting weird integral evaluation from Wolfram Alpha

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

Check this out. I hand-evaluated this integral and my pretty sure the answer is zero, but Wolfram returns the value $4i\pi$ instead.[image]

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is correct. You're making a mistake in applying the Cauchy integral theorem (as in your other question). Check out the residue theorem.

Comment: Oh then my Mathcad is wrong like I am. It's giving me zero too. Hey thanks for your reply.

Comment: My mistake was in applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for contour integrals without checking that its conditions are fully satisfied: in the above example, the integrand does not have a primitive at at $t=\pi$ for instance, so the FTC does not apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with WA.  The first piece is zero.  For the second, let $z=e^{i t}$ and work the following contour integral:

$$\begin{align} 6 \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{2+3 z} = 2 \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(2/3)+z}\end{align}$$

The integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=-2/3$, which is inside the unit circle.  The result follows.